# How to append a string to shell's last executed list (which is accessing by Up-key)?

Tags: shell, zsh

The question doesn’t consist any further details. Obviously the faster solution will be the better. Relogging is too long by time.

Comment: I'll remove this ambiguity/strange question as soon as you, gentlemen, provide some acceptable answer.

Comment: Bad questions get bad answers. So, press UP-key and append a string by typing it.

Comment: I have no pretenses to <your> terminology guys. Synonyms are obsolete, ok.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "append a string"? Do you want to add a new entry to the command history, or do you want to append something to the last entry in the list (or all entries in the list)? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical name for what you call "last executed list" is `history`.

Usually, every command that your user executes is added to it. However, depending on your shell, you can edit the `history`-file and add your own lines. For `bash`, this file is `~/.bash_history`.

Comment: I need to relog to make such editing working.

Comment: What do you mean by "relog"? Start a new session?

Comment: Yes. A new session.